# How to use the slug from Friendly_id in a nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes, friendly-id

I am having a hard time making the slug from Friendly_id in a nested route when editing and creating?  the routes look great for show.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/test/tester2
```

This is the URL I am getting when i try to edit tester2 is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/2/tester2/edit
```

What i would like to see is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/test/tester2/edit
```

Here is my code.

team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :videos
  ...
end
```

video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :team
  ...
end
```

routes.rb

```
...
resources :teams, :path => '', :except => [:index] do 
  resources :videos, :path => '', :except => [:index] do
    get 'full_res_download'
    get 'web_download'
  end
end
...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What helper are you using to generate this URL: http://0.0.0.0:3000/2/tester2/edit. Is it something like this: edit_tester_tester2_url(@tester,@tester2)

Comment: @Adam edit_team_video_path(@video.team_id, @video)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it will work if you use this as your url helper instead:

```
edit_team_video_path(@video.team, @video)
```

If you give it the id explicitly, that's what it will use.