# How to differentiate between :ids in routes/URL that belong to different models using FriendlyID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm wondering how to generate a url that includes friendly ids for two different models. For example, if you have a post titled 'Rails Tutorial' and belonging to a particular User named 'Michael', and they each use a slug in place of their ID, how would you generate a url that looks like site.com/michael/rails-tutorial.

If you set your route to be:

```
get ':id/:id' => 'posts#show', as: 'show_post'
```

the URL will either be michael/michael or rails-tutorial/rails-tutorial, yet the way Friendly_id works from what I know is that your slug is represented by :id, so you can't configure it to work with get ':user_id/:post_id'.

I'm sure I just don't understand FriendlyID enough. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726665/how-to-use-the-slug-from-friendly-id-in-a-nested-route . You might get the idea. Try to add some code, showing what you did, this will make it easy for people to help you and you will get more response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the url you’re looking for, you’ll need to nest your routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

This will give you the route:

```
localhost:3000/users/slug/post/slug
```

You’ll also have to `extend FriendlyId` in each model, add the slug to each model in a migration and use `.friendly` in the controller action(s).